# C++, ternary operator, std::cout

Tags: c++, printing, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

How to write the following condition with a ternary operator using C++

```
int condition1, condition2, condition3;
int / double result; //int or double
....
std::cout << ( condition1: result1 : "Error" ) 
          << ( condition2: result2 : "Error" )
          << ( condition3: result3 : "Error")...;
```

Comment: ternary operator is `cond ? exp1  : exp2` . You have used `: :` Other than that, I don't think there is anything else to say!

Comment: @Diff: Oh yes, there is, see my answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Depends on what type is `result1, result2` etc.

`expressionC ? expression1 : expression2` isn't valid for all types of `expression1` and `expression2`. They must necessarily be convertible to a common type, roughly speaking (exact rules and exceptions can be read in the standard). Now, if `result`s are strings, then you do it like this:

```
std::cout << ( condition1 ? result1 : "Error" ) 
                         ^^^
          << ( condition2 ? result2 : "Error") 
                         ^^^
          << etc.
```

But if results are integers, for example, you can't do it.

HTH

Comment: And what about conversion of result to char?

Comment: @Johnas: no, that won't do. `"Error"` is of type `const char[6]`. `char` and `const char[6]` are different incompatible types

Comment: It looks like since C++11 you can do `(condition1 ?  to_string(result1) : string("Error"))` if the type of result1 is int, double, or another type accepted by to_string(). I've no idea if that's good practise, but it should be ok for quick debugging etc at least. Pretty new to C++ though, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @NotEnoughData Yes, you can indeed use `to_string` but then your formatting might not work properly, e.g. using `scientific` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `condition ? true-value : false-value`.